# Highchart: x- highchart change dateTime LabelFormats dynamically based on button(hours,day,week,month,qtr,year)

Tags: highcharts

Highchrt:on click hours button on x-axis date format will be hours, on click day button on x-axis will be day(day of the week(mon,sun,tue,etc)) need to show like week,day,month,qtr,year.

```
if (e.rangeSelectorButton.type === "month") {
  this.update(
    {
      minorTickInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
    },
    false
  );
}
if (e.rangeSelectorButton.type === "year") {
  this.update(
    {
      tickInterval: 12 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
      minorTickInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
    },
    false
  );
}
if (e.rangeSelectorButton.type === "week") {
  this.update(
    {
      tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
      minorTickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
    },
    false
  );
}
if (e.rangeSelectorButton.text === "Qtr") {
  this.update(
    {
      tickInterval: 4 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
      minorTickInterval: 4 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
    },
    false
  );
}
if (e.rangeSelectorButton.text === "Day") {
  this.update(
    {
      tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
      minorTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
    },
    false
  );
}
```

Comment: What's your problem? Looks like you already have an answer.

Comment: Hi @Sravan, Could you describe the problem more precisely? Also, some live example would be very useful.

Comment: on click hours button, on x-axis label will be in series of hour {[1h,2h,3h etc.,]} only, and same as on click day button x- axis label will be series of days[1d,2d,3d,] only, need to show, like week, month, qtr and year for all button click on x-axis format will be change based button click .

Comment: Hi @Sravan, Sorry for the late response. It looks like all you need to set is the `rangeSelector.buttons` Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9hery38f/ and do not hesitate to ask in case of any further questions.